# how to reattach the IQueryable object to a new instance of Context object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

i want to save the last searched query in a global variable and when i use that in another method it says :

ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

```
IQueryable lastQry = null;

private void SearchMethod()
{
   using(var ctx = new entityContex())
   {
      var qry = ctx.Table1.Where(t=> t.Name.StartWith(txtName.Text)).Take(100);

      lastQry = qry;

      dgvResult.DataSource = qry.ToList();
   }
}

private void RefreshResult()
{
   using(var ctx = new entityContex())
   {
      if(lastQry != null)
      //here is the Error ! <<---------------->>
      dgvResult.DataSource = lastQry.ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: What type of context are you using (`DbContext` or `ObjectContext`)?

Comment: its Object Context ,im using EF 6.0 database first model

Comment: Do you want to store the *results* of the last query, or store the *query itself* so that it can be executed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create and store a delegate which runs the query:

```
Func<entityContex, IQueryable</*Table1 type*/>> queryExecutor = null;

private void SearchMethod()
{
   using(var ctx = new entityContex())
   {
      queryExecutor = c => c.Table1.Where(t=> t.Name.StartWith(txtName.Text)).Take(100);

      var qry = queryExecutor(ctx);

      dgvResult.DataSource = qry.ToList();
   }
}

private void RefreshResult()
{
   using(var ctx = new entityContex())
   {
      if(queryExecutor != null)
      dgvResult.DataSource = queryExecutor(ctx).ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: the queryExecuter Func simply keep instance of context and do not let it dispose, is it?

Comment: @patachi: No, `queryExecutor` accepts the context as a parameter, then invokes the query against that context. The only thing captured in the Func is the value `txtName.Text` had when the Func instance was created.

Comment: really! and this means all the tables records that ctx bring to RAM will be disposed with these way ,i have some problem with define an instance of the entityContex as static member of class :D

Comment: @patachi, yes, the context will be disposed as expected, and won't be reused by the Func after disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the `IQueryable`, store the list:

```
List<Table1> lastQry = null;

private void SearchMethod()
{
 using(var ctx = new entityContex())
 {
   var qry = 
     ctx.Table1
       .Where(t=> t.Name.StartWith(txtName.Text))
       .Take(100)
       .ToList(); // <--

   lastQry = qry;
   dgvResult.DataSource = qry;
 }
}

private void RefreshResult()
{
  using(var ctx = new entityContex())
  {
    if(lastQry != null)
      dgvResult.DataSource = lastQry;
  }
}
```

Comment: This could propably lead to a high memory usage if the last query returns a huge amount of data, and the time to the next query is high

Comment: @boindiil: it doesn't return **huge** amount of data because of `.Take(100)`.

Comment: Thats true for this special case ;) I just want to point out to consinder this, when using this solution for the queries in general.

Comment: tnx but ,we have several user that working on the searched items and doing some kind of delete,edit,... stuff concurrently on the items and we need to the filtered searched result should be up to date, i solve the problem by using an static instance of context but im liiking for better way ;D